# How to switch on notifications for Azure DevOps PR review comment set to resolved

Tags: azure-devops

When a user hits Resolve on a review comment I made in a PR, I would expect to see a notification in my emails but I do not seem to be getting them.

Here are the options available to me in DevOps:

[image]

Here are the options assigned to my user:

[image]

For reference, this is the section I'd expect to get updates for when set to Resolved:

[image]

I'd imagine it to work similar to how it works in GitHub. Currently I'm relying on team members to @mention me.

I am an employee of an organization. Could it be that the option has been removed from me in some group policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could it be that the option has been removed from me in some group policy?

I am afraid there is no such specific settings to get the notifications for Azure DevOps PR review comment set to resolved.

We could only defined the notification for the Pull request changes. But the [default and supported notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAAxE.png) and [supported event types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/oob-supported-event-types?view=azure-devops) do not support to check the state of the PR review comment.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]